# Reliable string concatenation in embedded system using C language

Tags: c, embedded, concatenation, strcat

I'm currently working on a piece of code that will send some XML data as string via Ethernet. The data should be constructed first, in order to be sent to the socket. I'm using STM32F4xx type microcontrollers and using IAR EWARM embedded developement environment.

I've been using the following function:

```
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(len1+len2+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result+len1, s2, len2+1);//+1 to copy the null-terminator
    return result;
}

char* data = concat("<data>\n<items>\n<radar x=\"", "1"); 
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n<radar v=\"");
data = concat(data, "1");
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n</items>\n</data>");
len = strlen(data);

Socket_Send(data,len);
```

The ethernet server output results the following:

```
Send:(09:41:17) alive
Rec:(09:41:17)<data>
<items>
<radar x="1"></radar>
<radar v="1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:41:18) alive
Rec:(09:41:18)<data>
<items>
<radar x="1"></radar>
<radar v="1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:41:18) alive
Rec:(09:41:18)<data>
```

It sends the data correctly for 2 times, then writes only 6 characters. How do I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance..

**EDIT 1:**
Suggested code:

```
data = concat("<data>\n<items>\n<radar x=\"", "1"); 
char *tmp = data;
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n<radar v=\"");
free(tmp);
data = concat(data, "1");
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n</items>\n</data>");

len = strlen(data);
```

Output:

```
Send:(09:51:38) alive
Rec:(09:51:38)<data>
<items>
<radar x="1"></radar>
<radar v="1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:51:40) alive
Rec:(09:51:40)<data>
<items>
<radar x="1"></radar>
<radar v="1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:51:44) alive
Rec:(09:51:44)<data>
<items>
<radar x="1"></radar>
<radar v="1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:51:44) alive
Rec:(09:51:44)8 ¹Õ"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:51:44) alive
Rec:(09:51:44)8 ¹Õ1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:51:45) alive
Rec:(09:51:45)8 ¹Õ1"></radar>
</items>
</data>
Send:(09:51:45) alive
Rec:(09:51:45)8 ¹Õ
Send:(09:51:45) alive
Rec:(09:51:45)8 ¹Õ
Send:(09:51:46) alive
Rec:(09:51:46)8 ¹Õ
Send:(09:51:46) alive
Rec:(09:51:46)8 ¹Õ
```

**EDIT 2 (POOR SOLUTION):**

```
char* data;
char* data1;
char* data2;
char* data3;
data1 = concat("<data>\n<items>\n<radar x=\"", "1"); 

data2 = concat(data1, "\"></radar>\n<radar v=\"");
free(data1);

data3 = concat(data2, "1");
free(data2);

data = concat(data3, "\"></radar>\n</items>\n</data>");
free(data3);

len = strlen(data);
Socket_Send(data,len);
free(data);
```

**EDIT 3 (SOLVED):**

When the number of tags increased in the XML, the mem leakage happened as expected. As people suggested, I've tried ***strcat*** and it worked. But strcpy does not work in my compiler. I would strongly suggest to anyone who have the same issue to use strcat.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to keep the memory allocation separate from the algorithm. Sadly, experience tells me that programs that have a function somewhere, which returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, are almost certainly have memory leaks.

Comment: Side note: use `strcpy,strcat` instead of `memcpy,memcpy`.

Comment: Side note #2: There doesn't seem to be any need for all the runtime concatenations to begin with. All your strings are constant, so you might as well just statically allocate a single string. On top of the additional safety (achieved by avoiding dynamic memory alocation/deallocation), you'll also improve your runtime performance, and moreover - keep it constant, as the string will reside at the same memory address throughout the execution of your program (no unexpected caching impact, etc). Constant execution time is usually considered a crucial aspect in embedded systems.

Comment: The implementation has a serious memory leak issue already mentioned, but the method of string concatenation can have serious performance impact for the reasons discussed [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) - in addition to the performance impact and non-deterministic nature of dynamic memory allocation in the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of memory leak in calls below:

```
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n<radar v=\"");
```

Correct the leak and your program should work as expected.

One possible fix:

```
{
  char *tmp = data;
  data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n<radar v=\"");
  free(tmp);
}
```

Also after `malloc`, check whether the allocation was successful.

Comment: Make sure there are no leaks in receiving side also. I would suggest using valgrind tool.

Comment: Receiving side is a comm operator

Answer (score 1):

Depending on needs an context you could also re-write the concat function a bit. Make it take a re-allocate-able buffer as first argument. Then free it inside allocate and return new ptr.

```
char *concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = s1 ? strlen(s1) : 0;
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2) + 1;
    char *result;

    result = malloc(len1 + len2);
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2);
    free(s1);

    return result;
}
```

And then in your other code say:

```
size_t len;
char *data = NULL;

data = concat(data, "<data>\n<items>\n<radar x=\"");
data = concat(data, "1");
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n<radar v=\"");
data = concat(data, "1");
data = concat(data, "\"></radar>\n</items>\n</data>");


Socket_Send(data, strlen(data));
free(data);
```

---

As a side point it can sometimes be helpful to dump the data to console – to verify it is correct. Do something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void dump_txt(const char *buf, int len)
{
    int i;

    fprintf(stdout, "  ");
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", isprint(buf[i]) ? buf[i] : '.');
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

void dump(const char *buf, int len, int width)
{
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i && !(i % width))
            dump_txt(buf + (i - width), width);
        fprintf(stdout, "%02x ", buf[i]);
    }
    k = i;
    for (k = i ; k % width; ++k)
        fprintf(stdout, "   ");
    dump_txt(buf + (i - (i % width)), k - i);
}
```

Then you can say:

```
len = strlen(data);
dump(data, len + 1, 8); /* +1 to include trailing zero */
free(data);
```

which should give you something like:

```
3c 64 61 74 61 3e 0a 3c   <data>.<
69 74 65 6d 73 3e 0a 3c   items>.<
72 61 64 61 72 20 78 3d   radar x=
22 31 22 3e 3c 2f 72 61   "1"></ra
64 61 72 3e 0a 3c 72 61   dar>.<ra
64 61 72 20 76 3d 22 31   dar v="1
22 3e 3c 2f 72 61 64 61   "></rada
72 3e 0a 3c 2f 69 74 65   r>.</ite
6d 73 3e 0a 3c 2f 64 61   ms>.</da
74 61 3e 00               ta>.
```

Comment: check my edit. it works for now. +1 for explaining dumping data